# Prevent hourly tasks spanning days

Tags: ms-project, pm-software

Is there a simple way to block tasks from spanning days? I have some tasks such as interviews & exams which are 2 or 4 hours long but they obviously cannot span days.

However MS project is spanning them across weekends/days. So far I've been moving them manually but is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

Define Task type as Fixed duration, while changing resource assignment information, MSP will let you choose option like Duration is fixed and amount of work will impact or change duration to accommodate resource assignment.